# How to make object available throughout symfony2 app without repeating the query?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

**How can I share an object across views in Symfony?**

I implemented the class Serializable in my Entity, so that I could store the object in sessions. However, since my entity contains abstract methods I will need to implement the serializable method in my class, I believe that would be my last resort.

Until then, I'd like to find an alternative solution other than storing the Object in a temporary table in my database (It would be exactly the same as not doing anything because I would need to call the database in every controller that displays a view)

This is my scenario:

I have two files: `layout.html.twig` and `sidebar.html.twig`

I have a method inside my DefaultController called `buildSidebar()` looks as follows

```
public function buildSidebar($userId = 0) {
    $projects = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SuperBundle:Projects')->findBy(array('userId' => $userId), array('cratedDate' => DESC), 10);
    return $this->render(
            'SuperBundle:sidebar.html.twig',
            array('projects' => $projects)
    );
}
```

Then in my `layout.html.twig` file I have the following block of code in line 77:

```
{% render controller("SuperBundle:Default:buildSidebar", {'userId': 37})  %}
```

and when I test that out, symfony throws an exception saying:

`function controller doesn't exist in SuperBundle::layout.html.twig in line 77`

I've tried to embed the controller also this way:

```
{{ render(controller("SuperBundle:Default:buildSidebar", {'userId': 37}) }}
```

This method throws the exception `unexpected name of value controller`:

```
{{ render controller("SuperBundle:Default:buildSidebar", {'userId': 37}) }}
```

I also tried it this way, and same result `function controller does not exist`:

{% render(controller("SuperBundle:Default:buildSidebar", {'userId': 37}) %}

What am I missing? I followed Symfony's documentation to the letter, and nothing in there has helped me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can access to service from by a twig extention. 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

```
<?php

namespace You\UserBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;


class YourExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    protected $doctrine;

    function __construct($doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }


    public function getUsers()
    {
        $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
        $result = $em
            ->getRepository('yourEntity')->findAll();
        return $result;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('get_users', array($this, 'getUsers'))
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'your_extension';
    }

}
```

Or you have the possibility to include one controller in your twig view like :

```
        {{ render(controller('YourUserBundle:YourController:youraction')) }}
```

Source : http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-the-new-fragment-sub-framework

Comment: No problem we are all here to help each others :)

Comment: Turns out that twig keeps complainig about "controller" function doesn't exist... in my template.html.twig I've tried your way, the way th symfony documentation suggests, and a couple others that I've found on the internet. I've even tried to replace {{ }} with {% %} and it didn't work either.

Comment: Could you check my updated question? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I found the error, it's my version of symfony. I'm using 2.1.8 and in that version the function controller doesn't exist.

Comment: The functionality is described here : http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-the-new-fragment-sub-framework